# Anyone experiencing this with itunesconnect?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

When I am trying to upload a new built I get this error during 1am - 3am

[image]

Comment: Now I'm really curious: how did you figure out that this is happening only between 1AM and 3AM??

Comment: I usually work during those times  (1am - 3am GMT). I did encounter this more than once during this month and last.

Comment: Except India, China, HK and Singapore (iOS heavy) both sides of Atlantic is very quiet during that time frame. Is it not? either heavy flow from the first mentioned countries causing this error or Apple running some sorts of updates?

Answer (score 0):

yes
just refresh the page
if it shows this again wait for sometime and refresh the page

Comment: Nah I refreshed few times, logged out, used different browser and cleared cookies. :-)

Comment: as I told you, if it shows again, wait for some more time and try again, may be half an hour